# Echo specific hash value

Tags: ruby

Now, I'm not really sure what data structure this is...it seems to be a hash of two named hashes, @base and @messages.

```
#<ActiveModel::Errors:0x00000103a9cc80 @base=#<User id: nil, first_name: "Jimmy", last_name: "Thehat", profile_name: "Jimbohatboy", email: "awesomedog@hotmail.co.uk", encrypted_password: "$2a$04$MX40ryz4CU2jRuE4Pfy5.eRUz3rRZkmsvw7FXQyE6Bj1...", reset_password_token: nil, reset_password_sent_at: nil, remember_created_at: nil, sign_in_count: 0, current_sign_in_at: nil, last_sign_in_at: nil, current_sign_in_ip: nil, last_sign_in_ip: nil, confirmation_token: nil, confirmed_at: nil, confirmation_sent_at: nil, unconfirmed_email: nil, failed_attempts: 0, unlock_token: nil, locked_at: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>, @messages={}>
```

I know how to print the data in a keyed entry, but not with this. How could I iterate over the @messages hash?

Comment: will this work? `activemodel_obj.messages.each{...}`

Answer (score 1):

It is a ActiveModel::Errors object (as it says). Find a list of methods here: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Errors.html

For example:

```
obj.full_messages.each { |error| puts error }
```

Comment: Nearly, it's messages, though, not full_messages

Comment: @Starkers: That is right, since you asked for the (internal) `@messages` hash. Normally I would prefer to use the array returned by  `full_messages`, because it includes some magic (like translated attributes names, etc).